# Fetching data from mysql with bash

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I want to fetch the row details from mysql with bash.It is a small script that is suppose to run as a cronjob.

`sqlquery=$(mysql $MYSQL_DB  -u $MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -se "SELECT * FROM ip_list WHERE valid='Y'")`

Now i want to fetch the `$row` and place data for a specific column in a variable

In php i would do it as follows

```
<?php
$sql_query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM ip_list");
$sql_query->execute();
while ($row = $sql_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo $row['ip_address'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not just select the column you want in the query?

Comment: i will perform some check with every item and then update db accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pipe the output from the MySQL query to something like a `while` loop. eg:

```
mysql mydb -e 'SELECT * FROM TABLE' | while read row
do
    # whatever you want to do with the $row here
done
```